# HTML to Image: The Confusion Begins

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I load an HTML string into a webBrowser control's contents and tell the user to print-screen it.

I'd like to somehow either grab the webBrowser contents as an image, or somehow render this HTML to an image file that can be saved. Are there any free libraries to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been curious as to how this is accomplished myself.  I have not tried to do this, but here is a link to a CodeProject article that seems to describe the process quite well:
[HTML to Image in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/html2image.aspx)

Comment: this worked perfect! I just added a new constructor so instead of accepting a url and sending that to load in the webBrowser, it accepts html and write it to the control. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use a program called [Webshot](http://www.websitescreenshots.com/) and I absolutely love it.  It has a freeware version with upgrade available.  It even has a callable command line interface which can be used in an automated fashion.

[Link here.](http://www.websitescreenshots.com/)

Comment: I can't even get a color image with the free version, and the server dll is what I need and that costs money. As a poor guy I can't afford it, sorry.

Comment: Wow --sorry, I didn't notice that (when I downloaded it 6 months ago,  the free version included color shots and free command line).  If .pdf format is an option for you, you can use wkhtmltopdf.  Great program, all free, with command line that can be called on server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's bound to be a better solution than this, but I'm pretty sure it's better than your solution (I haven't checked out the other answers), so...

I have a working C# program that saves a bitmap image of a control.  Currently, the control is a textbox, but you could easily make it a web browser control.  The entire program is below.  The form has a button, button1, and a textbox, textBox1.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(textBox1.Width,textBox1.Height);
            textBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm,new Rectangle(0,0,bm.Width,bm.Height));
            bm.Save("image.bmp");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this would have worked too but I needed something to autodetect the size of the webpage and also leave out the scrollbars. thanks anyways though